Expected length of exit path for random walk with continuous, uniformly distributed turning angle
Let $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. Start at (0,0) and uniformly pick a random angle $t_0\in[-\theta,\theta]$. Take a step of length 1 in the direction of $t_0$. Pick another angle $t_1\in[-\theta,\theta]$ and take another step of length 1 in the direction $t_0 + t_1$. At iteration $i$, select $t_i$ and take a step of length 1 in the direction of $t_1 + t_2 + ... + t_i$. Repeat this process and stop when you reach a point that is at least 10 units from (0,0), i.e., until you exit the disk of radius 10 centered at (0,0). As a function of $\theta$, what is the expected number of steps taken before exiting the disk?
I.e., a sequence of arbitrary length $\pi\in[-\theta,\theta]^*$ characterizes a path as above. We say that $\pi$ is an exit path if it ends at a state outside the disk and if all proper prefixes end inside the disk. Let $\Pi\subset[-\theta,\theta]^*$ be the set of all exit paths. I think I'm asking for something along the lines of $$\sum_{\pi\in\Pi}len(\pi)Pr(\pi)$$ but this is of course extremely naive since $\Pi$ is uncountably infinite.
The article on Markov chains on a measurable state space seems relevant and suggests we need something like $$\int_{\Pi}len(\pi)\mu(d\pi)$$ but I'm not sure what $\mu$ should be in this case. Generally, I'm not sure how to setup the Markov kernel or the measurable space in this case.
One idea is that we can build a region $R_n$ of points that is reachable in exactly $n$ steps for each $n$. For instance, $R_0 = \{(0,0)\}$, $R_1 = \{(cos(a),sin(a))\mid a\in[-\theta,\theta]\}$, etc. Once we get to $R_2$, it seems intuitively true that some points are more likely to be visited than others. Am I on the right track here? Is it a good idea to partition $\Pi$ using these $R_i$? Do we need to assign a relative abundance to the elements of each $R_i$, perhaps using some continuous function? How should we relate the relative abundance of elements in $R_i$ to those in $R_j$ for $i \neq j$?

@tkw Not quite: the numbers aren’t iid; if $\theta = 0$ then all exit paths will take exactly 10 steps. If $\theta$ is small, it will take, on average, close to 10 steps rather than the $O(n^2)$-ish steps expected when $\theta = \pi$.

@tkw you definitely can’t discard the turning angle from the state, since this angle determines the arc of valid successor states.

@DanielM. thank you for your comment, you're right and i misunderstood the question (have deleted)

@DerekEgolf you're absolutely right that my earlier comment was incorrect, but i believe your system is still a Markov chain if you reduce the state space to triples $(x,y,\alpha)$ of coordinates $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and a "heading" $\alpha$ which at step $n$ is $\alpha = t_0+\dots+t_n$ --- this might be easier than considering the entire path.

Do we need to solve this recurrence relation: $$T(x,y,h) = 1+\frac{1}{2\theta}\int_{-\theta}^{\theta} T(x+cos(t+h), y+sin(t+h), t+h) dt$$ with $T(x,y,h) = 0$ for $x,y$ outside the disk? The $1/2\theta$ term comes from the uniform distribution
